# Disable calendar to sync events to exchange server

Tags: sync, calendar, exchange, privacy

I've added an event to my calendar locally on a phone. It was a meeting in the evening after my working hours. How am I surprised to realize that my stupid phone sync this event to exchange server and let this information publicly available to everyone on my work. How to disable such an updates? Local calendar should be local. I like how my phone download an information about ongoing events on my work and inform me but not vice versa.

Comment: Which version of Android are you using? And which phone? Have you tried explicitly adding it to your gmail calendar? A Google calendar shouldn't sync with the exchange server unless you have it setup to do that.

Comment: It's an android version 4. I've just selected "calendar" from a list where to place the event. I do not want to add it into google calendar either. There is no such thing like local and private calendar on android?

Comment: There are phone local calendars on Android. But the usual approach would be to mark your event as private so that everybody else just sees the event but no the name or any other information. This way, you don't have to maintain two calendars, plus you are able to coordinate you personal events with your businesses ones.

Answer (score 3):

Your "*local and private*" Android calendar is your Google calendar. When you've created that personal event it defaulted to your Exchange calendar. In order to avoid this is the future make sure that you create events in the calendar you want  to. Usually it defaults to the last calendar you've created an event in.

Comment: Google calendar is not private and is not local.